# How to get rid of Page unresponsive pop up in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

I have developed a small application,When I am trying to upload a text file containing approx. 80,000 records from UI(I am using chrome browser),
After 3-4 sec. I can see a "page unresponsive" pop-up on browser. Since we are saving 80K records It's going to take some time on back-end. If I am clicking on "Wait" "Page unresponsive" pop up is appearing again after few seconds.
Is there a way so that I can get rid of "Page unresponsive" pop up,or "Is it the issue with the chrome browser?
Note:When I am uploading 1000 records it is working fine.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you uploading using javascript?

Comment: @Burhan :Yes I am using javaScript.

Comment: That's the problem - you need to offload the uploading to the background, by using AJAX.

Comment: By saying JavaScript I means,I am using AJAX(calling it Asynchronously) only.

Comment: edit your question and add your code.